# Can we use Google Tink to encrypt a file using c#?

Tags: tink

I want to encrypt files using c# and those files should be able to decrypt in Android and IOS apps.
I want to know whether this can be done using Tink.

Seems c# is not supported but at least if I could do it in c++ and prepare a dll so that I can call using c#. Is this possible? If so could you please direct me to any sample codes?